# Defining an Ordinal type whose enumerated subtypes are not ordinal

Tags: haskell

I'm running into issues defining ordinal types whose values may or may not be ordinal.

Basically I have two types, an `OrderedType` and an `UnorderedType`

```
data OrderedType = One | Two | Three deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
data UnorderedType = Red | Blue | Green deriving (Eq, Show)
```

I have a type whose value constructors take either as an argument:

```
data WrapperType = WrappedOne OrderedType
                   | WrappedTwo UnorderedType deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

Basically, what I want to be able to do is have `WrapperType`s be ordered without
having to implement a `compare` function for `WrappedOne` and `WrappedTwo`.

When I try to compile the above I get the following error:

```
• No instance for (Ord UnorderedType)
arising from the first field of ‘WrappedTwo’ (type ‘UnorderedType’)
Possible fix:
use a standalone 'deriving instance' declaration,
  so you can specify the instance context yourself
• When deriving the instance for (Ord WrappedType)
```

Which makes sense, because the stock derived `Ord` instance of `WrappedType` will try
to compare all values of `WrappedTwo`.

In a nutshell, what I want to be able to do is this:

```
WrappedOne _ < WrappedTwo _ -- True
```

But without writing an `Ord` instance for each type.

How do I do this?

Comment: What should be the result of `compare (WrappedTwo Red) (WrappedTwo Green)`?

Comment: i suppose it should be `EQ`

Comment: I think you should use something other than `Ord`. Although it is not technically a law, I (and many others) think that `x == y` should imply `f x == f y` for all `f`, a law which your proposed instance would surely break. If you keep the derived `Eq` instance, your proposal would also violate my expectation that `x == y` iff `compare x y == EQ`.

Comment: How? `Red == Red` and `WrappedTwo Red == WrappedTwo Red`. Same is true for `One == One` and `WrappedOne One == WrappedOne One`

Comment: You're right: my original comment was not precise. I've updated it.

Comment: But, to say how: since you want `WrappedTwo Red == WrappedTwo Green` (if you accept that `EQ` and `(==)` should coincide), then a suitable choice of `f` which shows the problem would be `f (WrappedTwo Red) = False; f (WrappedTwo Green) = True`.

Comment: I see. The thing is, `WrappedOne` and `WrappedTwo` are comparable. It just so happens that when they wrap other types, the types they wrap are no longer relevant. So they are ordinal at the top level, just not at the level of their subtypes.

Answer (score 3):

Not 100% clear on what you want; I guess you want all values constructed with `WrappedTwo` to be considered equivalent?

```
newtype ForgetOrder a = ForgetOrder a

instance Eq (ForgetOrder a) where
    _ == _ = True

instance Ord (ForgetOrder a) where
    compare _ _ = EQ
```

Then you can define your type as:

```
data WrapperType = WrappedOne OrderedType
                 | WrappedTwo (ForgetOrder UnorderedType) deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

Yes it is a bit cumbersome to have to wrap and unwrap the newtype, and also cumbersome to write pattern synonyms to avoid it.  C'est la vie.

However, I'm worried that you want `WrappedTwo Red /= WrappedTwo Green` as well.   At which point I'm going to have to jump on the bandwagon with Mr. Wagner and say, whatever path of thought you are traversing that requires this, turn back and find another way.  One of the great pleasures of Haskell is that people *care about laws* [1].  You will find that there are very few libraries on Hackage which define law-breaking instances.  And for good reason: for example, `Data.Set` expects `Ord` to define a total order and be compatible with `Eq`.  A type with a law-breaking `Ord` makes a `Set` of that type completely nonsensical and broken.  But I confidently put all kinds of things in `Set`s without a worry in the world, because lawfulness is so ubiquitous in Haskell culture.

But if you're not thinking that... good.  Sorry for being preachy.

---

[1] I was quite embarrassed to find that the expected laws are not [documented with the `Ord` class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Ord.html#t:Ord).  Anyway my conventional understanding of these laws is as follows:

1. **Equivalence of notation:**

   ```
   x < y   =  compare x y == LT
   x > y   =  compare x y == GT
   x == y  =  compare x y == EQ
   x <= y  =  x < y || x == y
   x >= y  =  x > y || x == y
   ```
2. **`==` is an equivalence relation:**

   ```
   x == x
   If x == y then y == x
   If x == y and y == z then x == z
   ```
3. **`==` extensionality**  *(this one seems to be a bit looser than the others; for example the documentation for [`sort`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sort) presupposes that `==` may not be extensional):*

   ```
   if x == y, then f x == f y
   ```

   *(For f's which are definable from outside a given abstraction
   boundary; IOW different representations of the same value are
   allowed as long as the user cannot tell them apart.)*
4. **Totality of `<`:**

   ```
   If x <= y  and  y <= z  then x <= z
   ```

   *(Trichotomy follows from "equivalence of notation" with compare)*

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you don't do this, for the reasons I discussed in the comments: your `Ord` instance and `Eq` instance should agree, and your `Eq` instance should only equate things that behave the same. Instead, have a view of your data which only has the information you care to compare. So:

```
data Constructor = Lower | Higher deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)
data Wrapper = WrappedOne Foo | WrappedTwo Bar deriving (Read, Show)

constructor :: Wrapper -> Constructor
constructor (WrappedOne _) = Lower
constructor (WrappedTwo _) = Higher
```

Now, where you would have called `compare wrapperA wrapperB`, instead call `compare (constructor wrapperA) (constructor wrapperB)`.

Comment: this doesnt completely fit my usecase, as `WrappedOne` and `WrappedTwo` are just two of many such types. It would be equally cumbersome to write a `constructor` function for each type as it would be to write an instance of `Ord`.

Also, to address the comment above, it is totally possible that `f (WrappedTwo Red) /= f (WrappedTwo Green)`. There is plenty of precedence for this in real life. While red and green are not equivalent, a box wrapped in red is functionally equivalent to the same box wrapped in green.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative approach, if you are only interested in comparisons at the constructor level and don't need to lift the underlying `Ord` instance for the ordered component types, you can use `Data.Data` generics to order by constructor indexes:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
import Data.Data
import Data.Ord

data OrderedType = One | Two | Three deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Data)
data UnorderedType = Red | Blue | Green deriving (Eq, Show, Data)

data WrapperType = WrappedOne OrderedType
                   | WrappedTwo UnorderedType deriving (Eq, Show, Data)

compareCon :: (Data a) => a -> a -> Ordering
compareCon = comparing (constrIndex' . toConstr)
  where constrIndex' x = case constrRep x of
          AlgConstr i -> i
          _           -> 0
```

There's a `constrIndex` in the `Data.Data` module, but it throws an error when the type isn't algebraic, so the `constrIndex'` above is safer.

Anyway, with these definitions, we get:

```
> compareCon (WrappedOne One) (WrappedTwo Red)
LT
> compareCon (WrappedOne One) (WrappedOne Two)
EQ
> compareCon (WrappedTwo Blue) (WrappedTwo Green)
EQ
>
```

This seems much safer than abusing `Ord`.